# Log when "database down" is returned by actuator health

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We would like to generate a CloudWatch alert if DB is down so I am trying to see if I can parse the response of actuator/health endpoint and log custom error code if DB down is returned by the response.

I found a few similar questions on StackOverflow but there was no solution provided there.

Comment: can you share the details with code which you have tried so that we can get more idea

Comment: That's the problem, I am not sure what to try. I was thinking of writing handler interceptor but not sure if that's the right way. Basically I need to know the output of inbuilt [DataSourceHealthIndicator] (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java) so that I can log custom error code and then configure a rule in CloudWatch to trigger an alert. @PatelRomil

Comment: Here is another approach I found (http://www.archive.ricston.com/blog/spring-boot-poor-mans-database-down-email-notification/) and it might work but not sure if thats the right way. There has to be a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the answer here if anybody else is looking to do the same
After doing the whole bunch of research, I figured there are 2 ways to do this.

1. Using filter - use ContentCachingResponseWrapper to cache response, read response using object mapper and then repopulate response using contentCachingResponseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse(). Looking at spring-boot git repository issues, looks like doing interceptor is possible but seems hacky and boot team recommends using the filter.
2. Using custom health indicator - auto-wire ApplicationContext and get hold of the Spring bean DataSourceHealthIndicator and then call health() function on it.

I have both the ways working but I went ahead with #1 because #2 is going to do the DB health check twice.